# Bidirectional mapping by one of two possible columns

Tags: java, database-design, hibernate-mapping

How would you define a bidirectional mapping between the following entities:

```java
@Entity
class Host {
    @Id 
    String id;

    HaGroup haGroup;  // needs mapping
}

@Entity
class HaGroup {
    @Id 
    String id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "primary_host_id")    
    Host primary;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "secondary_host_id")
    Host secondary;
}
```

I suppose HaGroup should be the owner of the association, so @JoinColumn works well here, but I stuck on the reverse direction. 
What I want to have in a Host object is a reference to a HaGroup which the host belongs to (either as primary or as secondary host) or null if it's not a member of any HaGroup.

Any ideas how this can be done gracefully?

Host and HaGroup DB tables are defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE host
(
  id character(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT host_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
)

CREATE TABLE ha_group
(
  id character(32) NOT NULL,
  primary_host_id character(32) NOT NULL,
  secondary_host_id character(32) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT ha_group_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ha_group_p_host_dc FOREIGN KEY (primary_host_id)
      REFERENCES host (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_ha_group_s_host_dc FOREIGN KEY (secondary_host_id)
      REFERENCES host (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the relation you want to have from Host side. I suggest you a design like below

```
@Entity
class Host {
    @Id 
    String id;

    HostType type;// this is a enum with values(PRIMARY,SECONDARY)
    @ManyToOne
    HaGroup haGroup;  // needs mapping
}

@Entity
class HaGroup {
    @Id 
    String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="haGroup")
    @JoinColumn(name = "primary_host_id")    
    List<Host> hostList;

}
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention that it is highly prefferable to leave the Host DB table without modifications. Otherwise I'd just add host.ha_group_id column.

Comment: two to one means ManyToOne relationship

Comment: "It depends on what the relation you want to have from Host side." -- The relation between Host and HaGroup is one-to-one: a host might be a member of only one group. From the HaGroup perspective, each of xxx_host_id fields refers to only one host.